# Build vs pre-compiled binaries

Tags: build

I've never understood the advantage of building over just using pre-compiled binaries. Can anyone explain why someone would go to the extra effort and time to build their own binaries rather than using the provided pre-build ones?

Comment: What? This question lacks lots of detail.

Comment: @DaveRook I've reviewed this a couple of time now and I think the question is Who? not `What?` for this case. also flagged as "primarily opinion-based" as well he is asking just for that opinions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a custom build, you can specify some specific flags, options or optimization for your own system. If you're using a pre-build one with an older architecture, for example SSE2, you may not have some advantaged of the new AVX instructions on your system. Or reversely, your old computer may not run the newly pre-built AVX2 binaries. Or when you need more speed or less memory usage you can change the optimization mode which can't be satisfied with a prebuilt

Comment: Ah right, so its only useful if you are going to go in and do some fancy stuff with the make files for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about software development.

People would use their own binaries because it suits a specific purpose where other available binaries do not.

Or, in the case where an existing binary does the job, the license may not allow it to be used in the given environment or, there is concern how long the binaries will be supported for your platform.